# Conditional format entire sheet using Openxlsx in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have data in R thats currently 645 rows by 94 columns.  But for a reproducible data lets just take the "iris" dataset.

I want to save that out as an excel with conditioning formatting where every cell that contains "A" gets highlighted. I know I can do something like this:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Data")
       
writeData(wb, "Data", iris)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Data", cols = 1:5, rows = 1:151, type = "contains", rule = "A")

saveWorkbook(wb, "iris.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

But my question is, I had to manually write in:

```
cols = 1:5, rows = 1:151
```

But what if I just want it to be every cell?  I.e. my data thats 645x94 might be 650x100 the next time I run the script, and I dont want to keep changing that text.  How can I just make it default to the whole thing?

Comment: You can use `cols = seq_along(iris), rows = seq_len(nrow(iris))`.  Replace the `iris` with the actual data object name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some basic functions to get the size of your data.

Try:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Data")
       
writeData(wb, "Data", iris)
col_num <- ncol(iris)
row_num <- nrow(iris)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Data", cols = 1:col_num, rows = 1:row_num, type = "contains", rule = "A")

saveWorkbook(wb, "iris.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```